# $l^\infty$ is not separable

Tags: real-analysis

I recently the study the following proposition in a notes: I add the image for the reference

[image]

My don't know exactly all "why?" parts in the proof but I'm trying to undertstand it. Here's my reason and anyone let me know if I'm wrong.

First ''why'': Since $I \neq J$ means the sequences $e_I$ and $e_J$ differ in atleast one place, so in that place the supremum attains the value $1$.

Second "why": Since $\Bbb{N}$ has $2^{\aleph_0} $ subsets, $\mathcal{B}$ has uncountable open balls.

Third "why":  (I don't know)

Fourth  "why": Since it is dense

Fifth "why": (I assume the third)Since  we have uncountable disjoint open balls

Any help?

Comment: Why do we even need the fifth "why"? If for each open ball there is an element of $S$ contained in it the there is a surjection $S\mapsto \mathcal B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments are correct.

For disjointness of the balls $B(e_I, \frac12)$, just use the triangle inequality and that $d(e_I, e_J)=1$.

Comment: I explain what you have saying, please correct it! Assume $I \neq J$ and $y_n \in B(e_I,1/2) \cap B(e_J,1/2)$ implies $d(e_I,y_n)<1/2$ and $d(e_J,y_n)<1/2$. Now $d(e_I,e_J) \leq d(e_I,y_n)+d(y_n,e_J)<1/2+1/2=1$, so we have $d(e_I,e_J)<1$, a contradiction. Am i right?